# Microsoft SharedView crashes now with IE9 RTM, what is a good alternative?

Tags: windows, software-rec, crash, screen-sharing

I've been quite reliant on MS [SharedView](https://web.archive.org/web/20160506170642/http://connect.microsoft.com/site94).  I have found it to be faster than VNC, and also allows for highlighting of the other person's screen without needing to take control of the mouse and can be used behind a NAT firewall very easily.

With the release of IE9, SharedView now [crashes](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304094920/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharedviewteamblog/archive/2011/03/18/sharedview-update-issue-with-ie9.aspx) and a fix does not seem forthcoming.  Are there any fast alternatives that allow for the same features (easy use behind a firewall, speed, and highlighting).

[UPDATE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/collaborate/connect-redirect?ContentID=6415&SiteID=94):

> Welcome to Microsoft SharedView  Effective January 31, 2012, the
> SharedView service has been discontinued. For information about
> Microsoft services that deliver similar features (such as Office 365
> and Lync Online) and free trial offers, visit
> http://www.microsoft.com/office365.

Comment: Geez, I rely on sharedview all the time.  downloaded IE9 and now I am stuck.  I sure hope this is solved.

Comment: Update on their [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharedviewteamblog/archive/2011/04/06/update-on-sharedview-ie9-issue.aspx) doesn't look good.  Will either take months to fix, or fix will never come.  Worst part is they won't say which one.

Comment: I tried Mikogo, which was a bit noisy.  Join.me is a pretty simple alternative that I am currently using.  Downside is that you cannot switch who is sharing screens, only the initiator can share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced the same.  I've been using Live Meeting (paid) and Join.Me (free) since.